# Dynamically loaded image returning outerHeight of 0 (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, dynamic-data

It seems that for some reason the `.load` method is not working. here in my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imgHeight;
    $('body').prepend('<img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8266/8653931785_4a8d43164f.jpg" class="select" />');
    if($('img.select').prop('complete')) {
       imgHeight = $('img.select').outerHeight();
    }else{
        $('img.select').load(function() {
            imgHeight = $('img.select').outerHeight();
        });    
    }
    $('body').prepend('<p>Image Height: ' + imgHeight + '</p>');
});
```

and a link to a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcarleton/2Dx5t/)

After the example is run a couple times(and I assume the image is cached) it will successfully retrieve the correct height. This tells me that `if($('img.select').prop('complete'))` is working properly.

What am I missing here?

(tested in Chrome and FF)

EDIT:
Alright, now what if I want to check more than one image if they are loaded?
`$('img.select').prop('complete')` only tests the first element that matches the selector.
http://jsfiddle.net/hcarleton/2Dx5t/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit** Updated to use [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of deprecated `load()`

`load()` is aysnchronous, so will not set the value of `imgHeight` before your call to `$('body').prepend('<p>Image Height: ' + imgHeight + '</p>');`. Also the `load()` event handler function is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8.

It would be best to attach a delegated load listener to the body for any images with the `.select` class. In the callback of that event handler, you can detect the image height.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').one('load', 'img.select', function(e) {
        var imgHeight = $('img.select').outerHeight();
        $('body').prepend('<p>Image Height: ' + imgHeight + '</p>');
    });    

    $('body').prepend('<img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8266/8653931785_4a8d43164f.jpg" class="select" />');
});
```

Comment: load() here is used to bind a event using a callback function, not a function. You have the asynchronous function .load() but it has a different sig.

Comment: also turns out that the load() event handler is deprecated as of jquery 1.8. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2Dx5t/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var imgHeight;
    $('body').prepend('<img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8266/8653931785_4a8d43164f.jpg" class="select" />');
    $("img").one('load', function () {
        imgHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
        $('body').prepend('<p>Image Height: ' + imgHeight + '</p>');
    }).each(function () {
        if (this.complete) $(this).load();
    });

});
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer? Copy and pasting doesn't help me. I need an explanation as to why this would work.

Comment: Sometimes load() event is not triggered for cached/broken image (old browser) or sometimes it is triggered more than one time due to browser behaviour. This explain the one and each. Your initial problem was that load here is an event (using callback function) called only when event has been triggered. So, in your initial code, imgHeight was never defined before you try to use it.